# Where is the best place to store globals in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I was wondering if there is the best practice on where to store global settings in a rails app. What I mean by that is i.e: I have a few globals defined that may change, but not likely and it seems inappropriate to store them in DB since they are used so much. For instance I have SYSTEM_EMAIL & SYSTEM_EMAIL_SIGNATURE & SYSTEM_STORAGE_ROOT.

Right now I keep them in environment.rb, but I'm not sure if this is the right palce to store them.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Accepted answer still stands as appropriate, however I since moved on to using  https://github.com/markbates/configatron , there are other options but I like configatron the most.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of my favourite techniques is to put a file containing the constants in directory `config/initializers/` (all files in this directory are loaded automatically) but with a section for each different Rails environment. e.g.

```
case ENV['RAILS_ENV']
  when "development"
    SYSTEM_EMAIL = ...
    SYSTEM_EMAIL_SIGNATURE = ...
  when "staging"
    SYSTEM_EMAIL = ...
    SYSTEM_EMAIL_SIGNATURE = ...
  when "production"  
    SYSTEM_EMAIL = ...
    SYSTEM_EMAIL_SIGNATURE = ...
end
```

If you want, instead, to load up all the constants in one big hash then you can load them as a YAML file. Create two files, one called, say, `config/initializers/email_constants.rb` and the other `config/email_constants.yml`. In the latter put something like:

```
development:
  :system_email: ...
  :system_email_signature: ...
staging:
  :system_email: ...
   system_email_signature: ...

... etc ...
```

Then in `config/initializers/email_constants.rb` put:

```
EMAIL_CONSTANTS = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/email_constants.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

This loads the entire YAML file and the assigns the value of the appropriate key (which represents the `RAILS_ENV`) to `EMAIL_CONSTANTS`.

The advantage of both of these techniques is locality. You can place all the constants that are related to each other (i.e. email constants in this case) in one file.  Also, instead of having the same constants spread across three different files (one for each Rails environment) you have them all in one file.

Comment: Thank you Sean. 
I like you approach the most - except I don't think I need to separate into email_constants.yml - I'll just keep everything in contacnts.yml

Answer (score 10):

Because such values often change depending on the environment you're running in, I store globals in `config/environments/development.rb|production.rb|test.rb`, with appropriate values for each environment.

Comment: How about constants that should be the same across dev/prod/test?  Rather than storing them in all three, is there one file that applies to all three environments?

Comment: The answer to my own comment seems to be /config/environment.rb.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thank you for posting that confirmation @Ben I was just searching for the exact same thing.

Comment: This seems like a much better answer than the one that was marked as 'answer'.  Why have the case statement for environments if Rails already does that for you?

Comment: Also note that if you use environment.rb you'll likely need to define your constants before YourAppName::Application.initialize!

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3 introduces the Application object. Even with Rails 2, you might want to store your globals in a similar manner.

Comment: Interesting, I started looking at Rails 3 recently - specifically routes, but haven't read much else. I will take a look. Thanks for the pointer Marc

Answer (score 1):

environment.rb is the place. You can add it to a Module and add it to the lib directory. then you could call it as Module::MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE. Both has strong points and weak points. In the environment.rb is ok but sometimes it looks messy. If all those global variables are related, you can group then in a module.

Answer (score 1):

I store such configuration information in a YML file. Refer to this [screen-cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file) for more details.

Alternatively you can use a gem called [app_config](http://github.com/cjbottaro/app_config).

Answer (score 1):

Normally when I'm doing something like this, I have two ways of doing this

1 - If my global variables are common to all 3 environments (development, test, production) , then i will store it in

config/environments.rb file

But lets say my values are changing upon the environment

Ex: my development environment  SYSTEM_STORAGE_ROOT is  '/development_root/' and testing environment SYSTEM_STORAGE_ROOT is  '/testing_root/'

then I will store them inside

config/environments/

As per the above example

config/environments/development.rb will have
SYSTEM_STORAGE_ROOT =  '/development_root/'

config/environments/test.rb will have
SYSTEM_STORAGE_ROOT =  '/testing_root/'

config/environments/production.rb will have
SYSTEM_STORAGE_ROOT =  '/production_root/'

hope this helps,

cheers,
sameera